# Zoned date time is not giving est time

Tags: java, spring, timezone, zoneddatetime

I want to convert the date and time to EST zone and I tried using calendar for some reason it is not converting the time even though it is setting the timezone correctly. And I am trying zonedDateTime and it is also working same.

```
ZoneId estZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime estTime =       ZonedDateTime.now(estZone);
 System.out.println(Date.from(estTime.toInstant()));
```

My output is:
Mon Oct 16 16:17:13 IST 2023.

But i set my zone id to America. And
estTime.toLocalDateTime is giving corrected time in EST but I am not able to convert it into Date return type as it is throwing Instant class errors

I need some explanation on this

Comment: Firstly, America/New_York isn't currently observing EST anyway - it's observing EDT. But more importantly, your question suggests you believe a `java.util.Date` value "has" a time zone. It doesn't. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: So we cannot convert ZonedDateTime to Date? It was working for a while but now it is troubleshooting me. So instead of changing the date return type to zonedDate time is there anyway to convert ZonedDateTime to date correctly

Comment: "So we cannot convert ZonedDateTime to Date" - you absolutely can, but `Date` *only* represents an instant in time, with a precision of milliseconds. If you expect it to do more than that, you'll be disappointed. (Fundamentally, I'd try to avoid using Date entirely..)

Comment: Can you help me with a code snippet which works well for my scenario if possible

Comment: No, because we don't know what you're trying to do. If you're trying to get "a Date that represents an instant in a specific time zone" then that's just not going to happen. (It doesn't help that you've said "it is throwing Instant class errors" without giving any more detail...)

Comment: *Can you help me with a code snippet which works well for my scenario if possible* Just leave out any use of `Date` entirely as Jon already suggested. That class was poorly designed, is long outdated and never could do what you want to do. A `Date` never could have a time zone. It’s its `toString` method telling a lie when it prints one. Read @JonSkeet’s link.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz y", Locale.ROOT))`. Just yielded `Mon Oct 16 08:03:39 EDT 2023`.

Comment: I want to convert the local time to EST/ EDt time zones. And i want to do using Date because it's my database type for that field

Comment: Using JDBC? And which data type in SQL? You don’t need to take the trouble with `Date` for that. Since JDBC 4.2 you can directly store java.time types through JDBC. Hibernate can do the same at least since Hibernate 5. *i want to do using Date* I am sorry, I read that as *I want trouble*.

Comment: This is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You want to store US Eastern time into your database. Fine. Then ask about that. I am sure we can help.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication but we need to use date for legacy purpose so i need one date object that can represent the current time as in EST

Comment: *we need to use date for legacy purpose so i need one date object that can represent the current time as in EST* Sorry if I wasn't clear: If you mean `java.util.Date`, this cannot exist. You are asking the impossible.

Answer (score 2):

### Use real time zone

> `ZoneId estZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");`

EST is not [a real time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Use such pseudo-zones only for presentation to the user, not for logic or data. Pseudo-zones are not standardized, and are not even unique(!).

And the time zones usually associated with “Eastern” time are currently observing [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). So the pseudo-zone label would be `EDT` rather than `EST`.

So, let’s use this:

```
ZoneId zoneNewYork = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
```

### Use *java.time* classes

> `ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneNewYork );`

Good. You captured the current moment as seen with the wall-clock time & calendar used by the people of the New York region.

To generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in brackets, merely call [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString()).

```
String output = zdtNewYork.toString() ;
```

To generate localized text, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`.

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

> `Date.from(estTime.toInstant())`

Bad. You needlessly involved the terribly flawed legacy class `java.util.Date`.

Avoid the legacy date-time classes. Use only *java.time* classes.

As for the behavior you encountered, the `Date#toString` method lies to us. While generating its text, the method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone. One of many reasons to avoid this class.

### JDBC

You commented on storing this moment in a database.

Your table column should be of a type akin to the [SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization_history) type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

The [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) standard maps the Java class [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to that type.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdtNewYork.toOffsetDateTime() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zoneNewYork ) ;
```

Search to learn more. This has been covered many times on Stack Overflow.

### Using legacy classes

You commented:

> we need to use date for legacy purpose so I need one date object that can represent the current time as in EST

The [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) class represents a moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. So asking for a `java.util.Date` object to represent a moment as seen in a time zone like `America/New_York` is impossible.

The replacement for `java.util.Date` is [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). Both represent a moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero). You can convert back and forth via new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

And going the other direction:

```
Instant instant = d.toInstant() ;
```

When converting, be mindful of possible data loss. The legacy class resolves to milliseconds while the modern class has a much finer resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

The [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) class, or rather its subclass [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), can represent a moment as seen in a particular time zone. If need be, you can convert back and forth to/from its replacement class, [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Avoid these legacy classes wherever possible. They are a bloody mess of poor design and wacky features.

If you have a specific case where you need to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, post a Question on Stack Overflow with those specific details.